# Return the updated ArrayList<Characters> after removing the specified element at the index

Tags: java, arraylist, character

I am trying to find out if there is a possibility of returning the updated ArrayList after removing the specified element at the index in a single line so that I can pass it on to the recursive function.
Below is a snippet of my code which tries to generate all valid parenthesis combinations given n pairs of "()" brackets.

My concern is in the recursive function call "findAllCombinations" where after some validations I want to remove one character at each recursive call from the arrayList courceSet. However `sourceSet.remove(index)` returns a character. Instead I want to pass the updated list after removing the character in one line. Is it possible ?

Note : The line below is syntactically wrong and just used for better illustration.

```
 findAllCombinations(sourceSet.remove(index), soFar + singleBracket, singleBracket); .
```

I did go through the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) but did not find any help.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks for your time.

```
public class GenerateParenthesis {

    char singleBracket;

    List<String> answerSet = new ArrayList<String>();

    char[] repoSet = {'(',')'};

    public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {

        String soFar = "(";

        List<Character> sourceSet = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            sourceSet.add('(');
            sourceSet.add(')');
        }

        findAllCombinations(sourceSet,soFar,'(');

        return answerSet;

    }


    public void findAllCombinations(List<Character> sourceSet,String soFar,Character toRemove){

        if(sourceSet.isEmpty()){
            answerSet.add(soFar);           // append to a answer set list containing all combinations
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<2;i++){

           singleBracket = repoSet[i];
           int index = sourceSet.indexOf(singleBracket);
           if(index!=-1) {
               findAllCombinations(sourceSet.remove(index), soFar + singleBracket, singleBracket);
           }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        GenerateParenthesis gp = new GenerateParenthesis();

        List<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();

        ans = gp.generateParenthesis(3);

    }
}
```

Comment: Would be an option to do it in 2 lines? Like `...{ sourceSet.remove(inex); findAllCombinations( sourceSet, soFar + singleBracket, ...`

Comment: Thanks @Fildor for the insight, however when the code comes out of each   recursive call I want the sourceSet to retain the original value of the sourceSet(which it had while going in the recursive call) which would not happen in this case.Correct me if I am wrong, any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: In that case, you need to do it differently, anyway. sourceSet.remove(index) will always mutate the list. You would need to pass a copy that lacks the element at index.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` (likely to most `List` implementations) is a *mutable* data structure: calling `remove` you modify the list rather than returning a new list without the removed element.

If you want the latter behavior, the quick and easy way is to do a copy of the list.

```
// (inside the if...)
// pass the original list to the constructor to make a copy
List<Character> sourceSetCopy = new ArrayList<>(sourceSet);
// modify the copy
sourceSetCopy.remove(index);
// use the modified copy
findAllCombinations(sourceSetCopy, soFar + singleBracket, singleBracket);
```